# How to load mesh to Cesium via Flask?

Tags: python, cesium, mesh, flask

I want to view mesh data in Cesium serving file from my local disk, make my own 'server' but I don't know how. Here is what I tried to do. Where am I making the mistakes?

(Under http://127.0.0.1:5000/tileset json file displays correctly in the browser.)

I have this catalog structure:

```
server.py
templates
  -index.html
static
  -b3dm files
  -tileset.json
```

This is server.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/tileset")
def tileset():
    return current_app.send_static_file('tileset.json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is part from index.html:

```
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
<script type="module">
    Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = 'token';
    
    const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
    
    viewer.camera.flyTo({
        destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(21.025, 52.270, 500)
    });
    
    var tileset = viewer.scene.primitives.add(
        new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/tileset"
        })
    );
</script>
```